# Crontab doesn't execute properly

Tags: ubuntu, server, cron

I am currently on a V-Server with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on it and trying to get my crontab to execute a node.js script that I have wrote earlier.
This is what my crontab currently looks like:

```
*/2     *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/wg/index >> /usr/local/bin/wg/log
```

When I check /var/log/syslog I'm seeing that cron executes the job, but the log I pipe the output to is empty and the script is just not working at all. I previously tested it on the same machine and it worked just fine.

I also tried to avoid the issue where the PATH variable that cron sets differs from mine, by just using complete paths to node.js and the script that I'm trying to execute.

Can anybody help me? I'm pretty clueless right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right above the crontab run add MAILTO, so it looks like :

```
MAILTO=youremail@gmail.com
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/wg/index >> /usr/local/bin/wg/log
```

if there's something wrong with your crontab, you'll get it to your email.
optionally, create the file yourself and temporarily make it writable with `chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/wg/log`. for ubuntu, I'd also move the log to `/var/log/wg/cron.log` just to keep it ubuntu-ish way.

Comment: Ok, so I'm slightly confused. Thanks for your tip with the MAILTO, I was thinking that the whole log gets piped to the log file. This was however not the case and when I checked the Mail I received, I was able to figure out what was wrong.
Apparently the issue was that I had to cd to the directory of the script before executing it, otherwise node/fs would be confused when trying to read a file from a relative path. I wasn't aware, that this could be an issue, but now I know better! Thank you very much :)

Comment: awesome, this is how I usually start to debug cron issues, so glad it helped you out